# Activities lifecycle in Android

Tags: android

I have an application that have three activities, lets call they A, B and C for convention.

A calls B with StartActivity.

When user hit the back/cancel button, I have to call Activity C, so I implemented in OnPause of Activity B to call Activity C and I need return from activity C, so I called Activity C with startActivityForResult and implemented the method onActivityResult in Activity B to get the return.

Everything is working fine, but when activity C finishes, the application is getting back to Activity A, and I need Activity B.

I have to call Activity B explicitly again or I made something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm really not sure what you want to achieve with this behaviour. Anyway, you get back from C to A, because you pressed the Back key, and didn't override it's behaviour in onBackPressed(). So the current Activity (B) just got finished, hence onPause() was called, so C started. But by the time C becomes active, you'll only have A and C on the Activity stack.

You need to override onBackPressed() in Activity B, and call C from there, forget onPause().

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't call another activity on hitting back button. Back button will pop activity(B) out of the stack. When you clicked back from Activity B Android will finish that activity and kill it. This is a standard workflow which better do not mess up. Place some button in activity B and call C for result from there, then you will be able to get a result in B activity.

Answer (score 0):

When you get to the `onPause()` in activity B, it is already shutting down, so when you return to it, it will be gone.
You can either, as you say, start B from C when done, or start C in B's `onBackPressed()` (and then return from that method without calling the super method). This overrides the default action to shut down the Activity.